# Object Properties restrictions - jena

Tags: java, api, jena

How can I determine the object properties restrictions for a class in Jena .

I have been trying to determinate if a class has a object restriction by using something like this:

```
         if (essaClasse.isRestriction()) 
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Restriction on property " + 
                        essaClasse.asRestriction().getOnProperty() );
                    }
         else 
                    {
                        System.out.println( "There is not restriction"  );
                    }
```

but I got :  "There is not restriction"

The owl file has a class (UserModel) which has the following restriction:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="&geosim2;UserModel">
     <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">UserModel</rdfs:label>
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&geosim2;Model"/>
     <rdfs:subClassOf>
         <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&geosim2;hasPeople"/>
            <owl:minCardinality   rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&geosim2;hasPhysicalPlace"/>
            <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">http://dit.upm.es/~perez/geosim/0.1.3/ns.owl#</rdfs:isDefinedBy>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">An instance of this class models a user simulation model.</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>
```

Comment: How did your code set essaClasse?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the implementation of [`OntClass#isRestriction()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/impl/OntClassImpl.java#OntClassImpl.isRestriction%28%29), we see that it requires the ability to find a specific triple in the underlying graph in order to identify that it is, indeed, on a restriction. Specifically, it looks for `?instance rdf:type ?obj` where `?obj` is specified by your profile.

Let us assume that you have an OWL profile in play. Then [`OWLProfile#RESTRICTION()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/impl/OWLProfile.java#OWLProfile.RESTRICTION%28%29) specifies that, in order to be interpreted as a `Restriction`, the resource in question needs to of type [`owl:Restriction`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/OWL.java#OWL.0Restriction).

You do have objects in your ontology that are of that type, but your code example does not expose whether or not you are referencing them. If, in your code example, your `essaClasse` is referencing `:&geosim2;UserModel`, then your code is doing exactly what it should. `&geosim2;UserModel` is *not* a restriction, but it is `rdfs:subClassOf` things which *are*.

**TL;DR:**

You need to list the super-classes of the class of interest (using [`OntClass#listSuperClasses()`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listSuperClasses%28%29), and then identify if *those* are restrictions. That will then give you the restrictions on your class.

In code that may not compile (written off the top of my head):

```
final ExtendedIterator<OntClass> superClass = esseClasse.listSuperClasses();
while( superClass.hasNext() ) {
    final OntClass aParent = superClass.next();
    if( aParent.isRestriction() ) {
        // Do interesting things
    }
    else {
        // Do other interesting things
    }
}
```